# Is there a method like Model::findOrFail($id) in eloquent orm?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a method in Eloquent ORM that will fail if row is not found in model?
Right now my method for deleting something from table looks like this:

```
public function delete($id) {
    $point = Map::find($id)->first();

    $point->delete();
}
```

But it throws exception when there is no `$id` in the model, how Do I check for that according to eloquent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent):

> All methods available on the query builder are also available when
>   querying Eloquent models.

You can use `findOrFail()` with Eloquent:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(1);
```

---

To handle `ModelNotFoundException` just add your logic to `render()` method of `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            abort(404);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I handle exception thrown by it?